# Is it possible to replicate an angle gradient layer style from Photoshop in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a design in Photoshop that I am transferring into Illustrator so I can have a vector version of the graphic. Everything is done except for the last step: the Photoshop file has a layer style that puts an Angle gradient on a stroke.

[image: Photoshop gradient]

In Illustrator, it seems only [Linear and Radial gradients](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html) are supported.

[image: Illustrator gradient]

What's the easiest way to replicate the Angle gradient in Illustrator? If replication is not possible, is there a close approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll get (easily) is on a stroke....

[image]

But... as you can see the angle is always 45° and always in the lower left. Even adjusting gradient stops won't change that....

[image]

(Note the 90° angle in the above created by color stops.)

You can then *rotate* the object so the angle hits the upper right corner.... but you can't really move it from that corner and retain any sort of angle in the gradient.

So, the best you can do is use a **shape** rather than a stroke, and configure a **Gradient Mesh** on that shape...

[image]

Then apply a clipping mask to the mesh object if necessary.

Mesh with clipping mask...
[image]

*Nowhere* near as editable or easy to apply.

<sub>Don't yell at me.... Adobe should address stuff like this. It's mind-boggling why Illustrator doesn't have conical or angled gradients in 2018.</sub>

These screenshots are from AICS6, but CC2018 offers *no additional improvements* in this area. (tested and confirmed)

Comment: Good point about Adobe not picking up the slack.
Adobe is solely focused on making AI, PS, etc. look cute/trendy and more social media friendly. Why should they focus on making it more functional when they've got us in their monthly death grip. They know we can't go anywhere else (yet) and that's why they don't care. Still gotta love Adobe though for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. Did you have to do anything special to be able to select the Stroke option on the Gradient panel? I think the middle option would work for me ("Apply gradient along stroke"), but I'm in Illustrator CC and it's stuck on the first option. Clicking on either of the other 2 doesn't do anything.

Comment: Aha! For anyone else reading, these other options are only supported for center-aligned stroke gradients: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1141240

Comment: Glad you figured that out @ZachRattner -- You need to leave the stroke on the default alignment... which is center aligned.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround, which can be useful, if stroke along a path or gradient meshes are not close enough:

You can make a circle with fake conical gradient fill. Actually it's a circle with diameter-wide stroke which have gradient along the stroke, but no fill. It can be also a pattern brush stroke. The pattern brush is a rectangle with linear gradient fill which is expanded. Both are discussed in several cases in this site. One link:

[How to create a simple grayscale image with conical gradient?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101079/how-to-create-a-simple-grayscale-image-with-conical-gradient)

Ok, lets have a circle with fake conical gradient:

[image]

The circle is splitted at eleven o'clock to put the start and endpoint there.

Move your stroke onto the circle and outline it. It's no more a stroke, but a filled shape:

[image]

Finally use the outlined stroke as a clipping mask for the circle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically I will create the vector in illustrator then open as smart object in PS and add the Layer style. That way you can change your ppi to what ever you want for output.
However if the file needs to be vector, here is a workaround for Illustrator: 1.> create a mask for the shape. 2.>Place simple strokes around the shape using different colors and then use the blend tool. 
[image: use blend options to create gradient effect]

[image: Apply the mask]